# Vertical shift of figures in the first page of landscape

Tags: subfloats, landscape

In a document I need to switch to landcape mode and insert some pictures. The pictures are the same size in all following pages and inserted in the same way. In the first page of landcape mode the pictures are shifted cca 2 cm upwards (towards the longer side of the page) when compared with the pictures in all following pages. I want the pictures to be aligned in the same way in all pages. What's wrong? Thank for your suggestions.

There is no formatting in the code, just plain insertion of pictures..

```
\begin{landscape}
%%%
\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{11.6cm}
\centering
 \includegraphics[width = 11.6cm]{pic/app2_broadlCRSopt.png}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{11.6cm}
\centering
 \includegraphics[width = 11.6cm]{pic/app2_broadlCRSreg.png}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{11.6cm}
\centering
 \includegraphics[width = 11.6cm]{pic/app2_broadlCRSsec.png}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{11.6cm}
\centering
 \includegraphics[width = 11.6cm]{pic/app2_broadlCRS6.png}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{11.6cm}
\centering
 \includegraphics[width = 11.6cm]{pic/app2_broadlNCSopt.png}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{11.6cm}
\centering
 \includegraphics[width = 11.6cm]{pic/app2_broadlNCSreg.png}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{11.6cm}
\centering
 \includegraphics[width = 11.6cm]{pic/app2_broadlNCSsec.png}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{11.6cm}
\centering
 \includegraphics[width = 11.6cm]{pic/app2_broadlNCS6.png}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

...

Comment: Your example can not be run so we can not see the shift you mean please always post _complete_ documents. (You can replace `\includegraphics` by `\rule{3cm}{1cm}` for whatever size shows the problem to make the file self contained).  However I would guess that the problem is your use of the `[!h]` option (you should never use h without using p and probably t, it leaves latex so few options.  Remove all the `[!h]` and add `\clearpage` between each one.

Comment: Perfect! As you said, the problem was the [!h]. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is your use of the `[!h]` option (you should never use `h` without using `p` and probably `t`, it leaves LaTeX so few options Using the optional argument to `figure` generally *restricts* the places where the float is allowed. Remove all the [!h] and add `\clearpage` between each one.